# How to resize side by side controls in MS ACCESS 2007

Tags: alignment, ms-access-2007, anchor

I have a form in which there are various fields, for ex. Two textboxes are side by side.
These 2 textbox have anchor property left,top and other right,top.

Now when I resize the form the controls are aligned to left and the other textbox to right.
But when as screen is maximized it leaves a blank space in between these two textboxes.

So then I made the anchor property of both textbox to both,both the controls overlapped.

PS: working on MS ACCESS 2007.
anchoring property above is Horizontal, Vertical

EDIT : In Normal window

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*Min Max Close*_

|  First_Name TEXTBOX                 Last_Name TEXTBOX   |

|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***|

When Maximized to whole screen it gives me

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_*Min Max Close*_

|  First_Name TEXTBOX .............................            Last_Name TEXTBOX   |

|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***|

And I need this way as below

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_*Min Max Close*_

|  F i r s t_N a m e     T E X T B O X   ........  L a s t_N a m e T E X T B O X   |

|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***|

I am trying to explain by doing all this as I am not allowed to upload a image, Sorry for that....

Comment: Maybe someone else will provide a real solution, but have you considered using VBA code to position the boxes around where you want them? We had a search form that had about 20 possible parameters, but each report had anywhere from 3 to 7 parameters.  We just created a table directing which boxes to show and where (left, top). You should be able to do something similar...

Comment: Doing it in a VBA code will have fix position, While maximizing form wont fill up the blank empty space in between them. I tried it using the Event on form resize. But did not helped me.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn : you may find my edit above question. Thanks

Comment: (1) Are there only the two fields on the line? (2) Are the field labels also on the line?  I have some code I was tinkering with that will expand the text fields based on form/window size, but didn't deal with labels.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn : yes, currently there are only 2 fields on a line with labels associated with the textboxes. Let me try with below solution and get back to you. :)

Comment: The following will NOT look right if there are labels on the line. It is a simple matter to account for the size of the label and adjust the VBA to handle properly.

Comment: I just updated the code so that it handles the labels you have on the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste the following code into your form, change the field names, and see what happens. The two fields will 'grow' as you increase the form width, yet maintain their Anchor. Note: I updated on 3/3 to handle the field labels.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim fviInsideWidth  As Integer
Dim fviSaveInsideWidth  As Integer
Dim fviFormWidth    As Integer
Dim fviFldWidth     As Integer
Dim fviFieldGap     As Integer
Dim fviRemainder    As Integer
Dim fviLblWidth     As Integer
Dim fviRLblToTxt    As Integer
Dim fvstrLLabel     As String
Dim fvstrRLabel     As String

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    fviSaveInsideWidth = Me.InsideWidth
    fviInsideWidth = Me.InsideWidth
    fviFormWidth = Me.Width
    fviFldWidth = Me.fldLeft.Width + Me.fldRight.Width
    fviRemainder = fviInsideWidth - fviFldWidth
    fviFieldGap = Me.fldRight.Left - (Me.fldLeft.Left + Me.fldLeft.Width)
    fvstrLLabel = Me.fldLeft.Controls.Item(0).Name
    fvstrRLabel = Me.fldRight.Controls.Item(0).Name
    fviLblWidth = Me.Controls(fvstrRLabel).Width
    fviRLblToTxt = Me.fldRight.Left - Me.Controls(fvstrRLabel).Left
    'Debug.Print "Open - InsideWidth = " & fviInsideWidth & "  Fields: " & fviFldWidth & "  Remainder: " & fviRemainder
    'Debug.Print "Open - Form Width  = " & Me.Width & vbTab & "Diff = " & fviInsideWidth - fviFormWidth
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()
    Me.fldLeft.Width = fviFldWidth
    Me.fldRight.Width = fviFldWidth
    Me.InsideWidth = fviSaveInsideWidth
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Resize()
    Dim ifldWidth   As Integer
    Dim ifrmWidth   As Integer
    fviInsideWidth = Me.InsideWidth
    ifrmWidth = fviInsideWidth - 1110
    Me.Width = ifrmWidth
    ifldWidth = Int((fviInsideWidth - fviRemainder) / 2)
    Me.fldLeft.Width = ifldWidth
    Me.fldRight.Left = Me.fldLeft.Left + Me.fldLeft.Width + fviFieldGap
    Me.Controls(fvstrRLabel).Left = Me.fldRight.Left - fviRLblToTxt
    Me.fldRight.Width = ifldWidth
    'Debug.Print "Resize - InsideWidth = " & fviInsideWidth & vbTab & "Form Width = " & Me.Width & " Flds: " & ifldWidth & " Right=" & Me.fldLeft.Left + Me.fldLeft.Width + fviFieldGap
    'Debug.Print "Resize Form: " & Me.Width & " Flds: " & ifldWidth
    Me.Repaint
End Sub
```